# Regex for USA phone number with country code prefix

Tags: regex, phone-number

I want to write a regex for a USA phone number with country code prefix. The formats should be

`+12345678900`
`+1 (801) 234 5678`
`+1801-234-5678`

Comment: Are you using just Python or Django?

Comment: I'm using it on Google forms, so I'm not sure of the underlying language

Comment: Ah ok I don't know why I was thinking Python. The below answer will work regardless of language.

Comment: Questions that ask ["Give me a regex that does X"](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285733) with no attempt are off topic on Stack Overflow.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this, which uses an OR (`|`) between your 3 formats. Can be adjusted to be more or less strict.

https://regex101.com/r/c9G5ZO/1

```
\+\d{11}|\+\d\s?\(\d{3}\)(\s?\d){7}|\+(\d[-]?){11}
```

Since it's US only you could force the first number to be a 1 and not a `\d`, like so:

```
\+1\d{10}|\+1\s?\(\d{3}\)(\s?\d){7}|\+1(\d[-]?){10}
```

Comment: Happy to help!!